# unable to run eclipse project on tomcat server(Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.)

Tags: eclipse, apache, jsp, tomcat

All of a sudden this error pops up.

Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start

I tried removing and reconfiguring server. It didn't help

the error log is given below

> May 24, 2015 3:17:32 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>       SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to   start.
>       org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component     [StandardServer[8005]]
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>           at   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       ... 7 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       ... 9 more
>   Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       ... 11 more
>       May 24, 2015 3:17:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
>       INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
>       May 24, 2015 3:17:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
>       INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
>           May 24, 2015 3:17:32 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
>           INFO: Stopping service Catalina
>           May 24, 2015 3:17:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
>           INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
>           May 24, 2015 3:17:32 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
>           INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the zip file of tomcat instead of 32 bit windows zip or 64 bit windows zip.

Adding a server- Window->Pref->Server->Runtime Env

Download link- http://mirror.symnds.com/software/Apache/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.62/bin/apache-tomcat-7.0.62.zip

Apache Tomcat download page
https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi